Puppeteer-Cluster Parallel Web Scraping Only Executes First Page Fully, Others Load Indefinitely
I am using puppeteer-cluster for parallel web scraping. My script is supposed to navigate through a series of web pages and fill out forms. However, I am encountering an issue where only the first page executes completely, and the subsequent pages load indefinitely. Here is my code:
const { Cluster } = require('puppeteer-cluster');

const args = [
    '--disable-features=site-per-process',
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
    '--disable-infobars',
    '--no-zygote',
    '--no-first-run',
    '--window-position=0,0',
    '--ignore-certificate-errors',
    '--ignore-certificate-errors-skip-list',
    '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
    '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
    '--disable-gpu',
    '--hide-scrollbars',
    '--disable-notifications',
    '--disable-background-timer-throttling',
    '--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows',
    '--disable-breakpad',
    '--disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages',
    '--disable-extensions',
    '--disable-features=TranslateUI,BlinkGenPropertyTrees',
    '--disable-ipc-flooding-protection',
    '--disable-renderer-backgrounding',
    '--enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess',
    '--force-color-profile=srgb',
    '--metrics-recording-only',
    '--mute-audio'
];

(async () => {
  const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
    concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_PAGE,
    maxConcurrency: 4,
    puppeteerOptions: {
        headless: false,
        args: args,
        timeout: 300000, // Increased timeout to 5 minutes
        monitor: true
    }
  });

  await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: url }) => {
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.waitForSelector('#Office');
    await page.select('#Office', 'PEKING');
    await Promise.all([
        page.waitForNavigation({ timeout: 0 }), 
        page.click('input[type=submit][value=Next]')
    ]);

    await page.waitForSelector('#CalendarId');
    await page.select('#CalendarId', '20804258');
    await page.waitForSelector('input[type=submit][value=Next]');

    await Promise.all([
        page.waitForNavigation({ timeout: 0 }), 
        page.click('input[type=submit][value=Next]')
    ]);

    await page.waitForSelector('input[type=submit][value=Next]');

    await Promise.all([
        page.waitForNavigation({ timeout: 0 }), 
        page.click('input[type=submit][value=Next]')
    ]);

    await page.waitForSelector('input[type=submit][value=Next]');

    await Promise.all([
        page.waitForNavigation({ timeout: 0 }), 
        page.click('input[type=submit][value=Next]')
    ]);

    await page.waitForSelector('input[type=radio]');
    await page.click('input[type=radio]');

    await Promise.all([
        page.waitForNavigation({ timeout: 0 }), 
        page.click('input[type=submit][value=Next]')
    ]);

    await page.waitForSelector('#main > form');

    await page.type('#Lastname', 'Lastname');
    await page.type('#Firstname', 'Lastname');
    await page.type('#DateOfBirth', '15.03.2016');
    await page.type('#TraveldocumentNumber', '9999999999');
    await page.select('#Sex', '2');
    await page.type('#Street', 'Street');
    await page.type('#Postcode', '25001');
    await page.type('#City', 'City');
    await page.select('#Country', '3');
   });
  cluster.on('taskerror', (err, data, willRetry) => {
    if (willRetry) {
      console.warn(`Encountered an error while crawling ${data}. ${err.message}\nThis job will be retried`);
    } else {
      console.error(`Failed to crawl ${data}: ${err.message}`);
    }
  });

  cluster.queue('<some url>');
  cluster.queue('<some url>');
  // many more pages

  await cluster.idle();
  await cluster.close();
})();

When I run this script, the first page in the queue is fully executed, but the other pages seem to load indefinitely and do not complete the tasks.

Avoid timeout: 0 and please provide '<some url>' so we can reproduce the issue. You are using the correct click/nav pattern, although if you're waiting for a selector unique to the next page, you can drop the waitForNavigation() calls.

The motivation for not using timeout 0 is you want to figure out exactly what error and on which line problems occur. With timeout 0 the script just hangs forever until you kill it, and there are no good diagnostics available or insight into what went wrong. Use a sensible timeout of a few minutes at the most. If something doesn't work within a few minutes, it never will, and the only sensible approach is to throw, catch, log errors and retry.

Also, await page.goto(url); can hang forever on certain sites that never manage to fire the "load" event. await page.goto(url. {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"}); is better.

@ggorlen What could be the problem with the script running on two pages of the same url? On the first page the script goes to the end, and the second page is always loading in the middle. Also they do not work in parallel.

No idea. I'd have to see the site and run the code to say. If you can't share the site, can you find a random public site that does reproduce the issue? Did you minimize the code to find the failing line? If most of this code can be removed and you still have the issue, I'd start with that, but right now the problem could be anywhere.

@ggorlen I got to the point that the script was running too fast, the site did not have time to fully load, so I used sleep(1000), but it turned out to be unstable and works every once in a while.

Replace the sleep with a more precise predicate.

@ggorlen Now I've found the problem. When I run several contexts in parallel, when I click on a button with type=sumbit, a request with type Document is sent to get a new html (the site uses jQuery).  This request cannot be executed, so puppeteer crashes with error Timeout hit: 30000 because it did not wait for the right selector from that html. But if it's one at a time, it works. What could be the problem?

No idea. I'd have to see the site and run the code to say.
